# Headless selenium exits immediately

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a headless web scraper. When it run the scraper takes a base url, scrapes the links on that page, and then scrapes the links it got off that page.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the scraper it pretty much immediately exits. When I run the scraper normally (non headless) it works perfectly fine.

These are my selenium arguments:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'),
                          options=options)
```

I've also tried adding these options but it gave me the same result:

```
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

How can I solve this? I'm trying to deploy this scraper to heroku and none of the things I've tried above worked.

Comment: what version of chromedrvier are you running?

Comment: The latest release, 91.0.4472.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically some website won't load in headless mode unless a user agent is specified.

To fix this I added:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
```

This fixed the problem of my scraper exiting immediately